# How to determine parameters of a normal distribution from a limited range of points?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

In an experiment my data points are almost normally distributed with `meanvalue != 0`. My problem is I can only detect positive points (located on the right side of y axis)

[image]

What is the best way to determine meanvalue and standard deviation of the distribution

Comment: why don't you just fit it to a normal distribution?

Comment: How do you know your data is normally distributed if you can only observe the right tail?

Comment: If you are having the normality assumption from the very beginning, and you know the number of negative data points (but not observing the actual values), then you are having a censored data, and you can try to maximize the corresponding likelihood to obtain the MLE. If you do not know that, then you maximize the truncated normal likelihood instead.